# Remove duplicate JSON keys in python

Tags: python

I have a 2M entries json that looks like this with some keys as integers that occasionally repeat and I'm trying to figure out how to remove all duplicates in a dictionary:

```
{
"1": {
    "id": 1,
    "some_data": "some_data_1",
},
"2": {
    "id": 2,
    "some_data": "some_data_2",
},
"2": {
    "id": 2,
    "some_data": "some_data_2",
},
"3": {
    "id": 3,
    "some_data": "some_data_3",
},
```

}

So, basically, I'm looking for a generic function that will iterate over dict_keys, look for duplicates and return a clean json. Tried flicking with `{ each[''] : each for each in te }.values()`, but to no avail.

Comment: if you execute this as a dictionary code it will overwrite the duplicates. Is that enough?

Comment: There are no duplicates in dicts. Just deserialize the json serialize it again and the dupes will be gone. Btw, what do you mean by *"I have a json"*? A file, a string, ...?

Comment: oh right. I just tried importing a full file with `with open as f: testData = json.load(f)` and the duplicates were automatically overwritten. thanks!